# How to add symbol at the beginning of every line that *doesn't* begin with [term1] or [term2]?

Tags: notepad++

I'm formatting some chat logs and I would like to add || before each line that begins with anything except either of the participants names.

Example:

```
Bob: hi
hey
Martha: yeah hi
```

I want to add || before the second line there, making it look like this:

```
Bob: hi
||hey
Martha: yeah hi
```

Is there any way I can do this for the whole 30,000+ line document using find & replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewritten according to comment**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?![^|\r\n]+\|)`
- Replace with: `||`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^              # beginning of line
  (?!          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    [^|\r\n]+  # 1 or more any character that is not pipe or linebreak
    \|         # a pipe
  )            # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
||          # double pipe
```

**Given:**

```
Bob Stewart|1494043962207|hi
hey
Martha|1494044016655|yeah hi
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Bob Stewart|1494043962207|hi
||hey
Martha|1494044016655|yeah hi
```

---

**Screen Capture**

[image]

Comment: I added an answer to this to show more accurate formatting - would you mind updating? Thank you!

Comment: That ended up putting || in front of all lines. The result that you showed is what I want, but that didn't get it for me. I made sure I was in regular expression and had wrap around checked.

Comment: @BecauseICanTBH: Strange, I've added a screen capture. What version of Npp are you using, mine is `7.6.3` 64-bit

Comment: I was running 7.5.6 but it appears to be doing the same thing in 7.6.3. Very odd. Any ideas?

Comment: @BecauseICanTBH: May be you have some hidden characters or spaces (or characters other than "word" character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) between the beginning of line and the pipe. What characters are allowed in the names?

Comment: There is a space in the names, between the first and last names.

Comment: Example: Bob Stewart|1494043962207|hi

Comment: @BecauseICanTBH: Have a try with: `^(?![^|\r\n]+\|)`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. That was foolish of me to not include that in my original post, I didn't think it would matter. Thanks again

Comment: @BecauseICanTBH: Nice. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression `^(Bob|Martha).*$` and replace it with `$0\r\n||` afterwards replace the `||\r\n` (as an extended replace) with just `||`. You can probably do this in one step as well.

This won't work for subsequent lines. So for example:

```
Bob: Hi,
are you there?
I only need minute!
```

Would only put the || in front of the second line. Constructing a negation can be quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been more accurate about how it's formatted now in my example.

Bob|1494043962207|hi
hey
Martha|1494044016655|yeah hi

That's how it actually looks now - I tried to modify your method to get it to work but I couldn't quite get it. What exactly do I need to change?

Comment: Please, don't use answer part to update your question. [edit your question instead](https://superuser.com/posts/1409228/edit)

Comment: Add also the result you're expecting.

Comment: See my updated answer, is it what you expected?